# Adaptive subdivision resolution cap

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to render a scene that heavily features micropolygon displacements. It works just fine at 50% 1080x1920 resolution, but at 100% my memory usage goes through the roof, to around 36gigs.

I believe this is due to the higher pixel count of a full resolution render, creating an inordinately high number of polygons per pixel.

How would one cap this adaptive subdivision to be limited at a certain amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the render tab under geometry settings. render px is probably what you need

[image]

Comment: the lower the pixel scale the higher the details. works the other way around keep that in mind